# Change site logo for specific content type and page

Tags: theming, 8

How to add different logo images for specific content type and page. It want to be dynamic.When user add content, user want to select logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create multiple custom blocks with logo image and display with page the page you need.

Comment: Thankyou @ananthakumar. I implemented this in my project. Working fine

Answer (score 9):

Do not know weather this method fulfill the requirements but you can take a look. As Drupal 8 creates a block for logo. You can create separate block for each content type and depends on visibility condition you can show.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Create a dynamic View Block and use that as your logo block.

1. Add image field to your content type
2. Create a View Block in `/admin/structure/views/add`

[image]

4. In View, for Fields, add your Image
5. **Click on Advanced** (far right), for Contextual Filter add `ID` .Provide default value, Content ID from URL. (**Note:** The view preview will go blank, which is normal, since the View edit page does not have a Content ID.)

[image]

6. Go to blocks (`/admin/structure/block`), and add the View block to a region. For Visibility settings select the content type that you want this to appear in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add your logo field to your specfied content type, then create a custom page template for that specified content type, get and add logo field URL to page template variables and use it on page twig file.

if you want more details tell me I provide it for you.

Comment: @steniya you're welcome, inform me about your achievement